# Detecting the grammar errors in a sentence with Stanford Parser

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, grammar

I am working on a research of fake news detection and one of my features is that, the grammar weakness indicates the news is fake.
Now I am facing a problem where i could not find a way to detect the weakness in the grammar. I tried to use Stanford Parser but I could not figure which classes to use.
I should say that I am using Java.

To conclude: the input for the parser is the sentence and the output is the number of error in that sentence.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Stanford Parser by this way:

```
java -mx150m -cp "stanford-parser.jar;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "wordsAndTags" -printPCFGkBest 1 englishPCFG.ser.gz <input-file>
```

where  contains your English sentences.

The parser will output the probability of the parse, and we can use that as an indicator of correctness.

Comment: I have no idea how to run such commands. I got this error Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser

Comment: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.html I think the reason is that you are not familiar with Java, and you should improve your Java skill, because it may affect your productivity on research implementation.

Comment: If you could show out your detailed code, it is much better for other people to help you resolving it.